# How many days should I wait for an answer to my Ubuntu related question?

Tags: discussion

What to do if I didn't get answers for my posted question for several days?
I have a problem with my computer highlighted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874017/need-a-solution-to-a-blinking-screen) as clearly as possible. I am just unable to work on my Ubuntu system due to this issue and I have to rent a computer from my friend to go on my research. I am just waiting for the suggestions to my problem and I keep refreshing the page hoping that someone has an idea..

Comment: Please littering the Q space with the same issue will also confuse the rest of us and make it difficult to follow. We're all volunteers here so at times we may be attending to our private businesses and may be hard pressed for time. I am trying to follow your issue but its difficult as you have up to three posts on this issue.

Comment: My advice to you would be to try and strip that question back a bit. You give a lot of information that is not really needed (like every step of your installation) that may cloud the issue. If you make it more "to the point", it may help people understand the core problem better.

Comment: I just think the whole installation part may help to solve this big issue. Because I had problems at those parts, I stated them together with their solutions (at least I found so). every other problem caused by the previous process, therefore I thought it would be clear to highlight the whole process.

Answer (score 6):

> What to do if I didn't get answers for my posted question for several days?

The first thing to accept when seeking help on a Q&A site or even a help forum is that you need to have ***patience***.  It can sometimes take days or weeks to get assistance and help on some questions, and you need to accept it may take a while to get an answer.

You've got two acceptable options:

1. Place a bounty (when you have sufficient reputation, though you do not have it currently), or ask someone with high reputation to consider helping by placing a bounty on your question, to gather more attention for it.
2. Put more information in your question, if you've got comments and such for requests for more information and details.  Usually questions go unanswered because they're either too complex to fix or because there's not enough information to debug it properly.  (In your case, there's probably not any more information to include).

A far less acceptable option is to edit your question to "bump" it to the top of the active list, but we frown on this because this has the tendency to be abused, and just makes noise and useless edits and such.

The core problem here is installation / GUI problems are some of the most trickiest ones to solve.  It can sometimes take a lot of time to get adequate answers or solutions available for these problems, because a lot of times it's specialized to a specific hardware.

---

As I am less concerned about reputation than others (thank you, moderator diamond), I will put a +100 bounty on your question to get more attention to it, and keep an eye on it for unuseful answers, etc.  (You caught me in a generous mood today.)

But normally, the answer is ***have patience, and a lot of it***.  A few days is nothing with some of the more complex issues, like this one.

Comment: I see,  I am just worried about being unwillingly ignorant of what happened at that very time...

Comment: @Sohib Unfortunately, there's not really anything else I can suggest.  There are *tons* of questions that don't get replies ever, and there's really no way to 'get more attention' to posts other than bounties.  Again, tricky problems can sometimes go weeks without a useful answer.